# __do_global_dtors_aux in C

Tags: c, mips

I'm compiling a C program for a MIPS embedded system.
GCC keeps sticking in stuff like __do_global_dtors_aux, frame_dummy, __do_global_ctors_aux.
How can I avoid that?

Resolved: I just "fixed" it by passing -nostdlib to gcc. Silly me for forgetting that

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using C++ instead of C. Perhaps you've accidentally capitalized the extension on your files, so they're `xxx.C` instead of `xxx.c`? You could also try `-x c` to get gcc to treat the file as C regardless of extension.

Comment: Thanks, but I just "fixed" it by passing -nostdlib to gcc.
Silly me for forgetting that.