# Disassembly of sections in a c program

Tags: c, objdump, disassembly

I wrote a very basic `Hello World` program to know about sections. After using `objdump` I got all sections. I am using `ubuntu 12.04`.

in output I found it like that :

> 1. Disassembly of section .init
> 2. Disassembly of section .plt
> 3. Disassembly of section .text
> 4. __do_global_dtors_aux
> 5. Disassembly of section .fini

I want to know what those sections are? what data they store? Specially `.plt` and `.fini`. About `.init` and `.text` I can guess, but what about others?

Comment: may I know how did you compile this file

Comment: first `gcc -o objectfile programname.c`
then `objdump objectfile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should google it : [here is the first result](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060). It's a good start to learn more about ELF format.

About `.init` and `.fini`, [it's here](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node3.html).

[Here is a list of the ELF sections](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/specialsections.html) with a brief description.

Comment: `dtor` means destructor, and I am using c, then how come I am getting `__do_global_dtors_aux`. Is it destructor or something else?

Comment: What's your compiler ?

Comment: I am using gcc on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Krishna Take a look at [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477494/do-global-dtors-aux-and-do-global-ctors-aux), this may help you. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741417/do-global-dtors-aux-in-c) can be interesting too.

Comment: I googled it and this thread was the first link ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

[From this handy page](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1060):

> The next section I want to mention is the .plt section. This contains the jump table that is used when we call functions in the shared library.

And [from this page](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node3.html):

> .fini
>
> This section holds executable instructions that contribute to the process termination code. That is, when a program exits normally, the system arranges to execute the code in this section.

Answer (score 0):

you might find this brief tutorial helpful. It also contains links to related literature.

"The linker demystified, part 1": http://www.rtos.be/?p=2166

I hope it helps.

Fernando